# flutter async function : _Future<String> returned instead of string value when subfunction is done

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to figure a good way to handle nested async functions I'm doing some tests with dartpad. In the following example I don't understand **why _Future is printed instead of the value (level1String) ?**
The output is :
toto
before await level2
before duration
after duration
13
after level 2
Instance of '_Future' // **my concern is here since "after level 2" is printed I should have reached the return statement**
after level 1
yeah!

```
import 'dart:convert';
import "dart:async";
import "dart:html";

void main() async {
  print('toto');
  await print(level1String());
  print('after level 1');
}

Future<String> level1String () async {
  print('before await level2');
   print(level2String());
  print('after level 2');
  return 'level1String';
}

int level2String () {
  print('before duration');
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    print('yeah!');
  });
  print('after duration');
  return 13;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await print(level1String());
```

should be

```
print(await level1String());
```

`level1String()` is returning the `Future` you need to await, not `print()`